# Weird CLR/Compiler behavior in Release Mode but not in Debug Mode

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, compact-framework, clr, dispose

I am developing an application for Windows CE and .NET Compact Framework 3.5.

**The code runs fine in Debug mode but when I change the mode to Release I get various exceptions**. I think it is related to some optimizations compiler trying to achieve in Release mode, like disposing and garbage collecting an object too early.

Following method, trying to insert entities to Sql Compact database, throws two exceptions(I think it is randomly):

```
public int Add<T>(List<T> entities)
    {
        int rowsEffected = 0;
        EntityMetadata metadata = GetMetadata<T>();
        using (SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
            command.CommandText = metadata.EntityMapAttribute.TableName;
            SqlCeResultSet set = command.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Scrollable | ResultSetOptions.Updatable);

            // Get generated Id, used in the loop below
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                SqlCeUpdatableRecord record = set.CreateRecord();
                PropertyMetadata pkPropertyMetadata = null;
                foreach (var prop in metadata.PropertyMetadataList)
                {
                    if (prop.Attribute.IsPK)
                    {
                        // Identify PK Property, avoid setting values (db automatically sets id)
                        pkPropertyMetadata = prop;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        object columnValue = prop.GetAccesssorDelegates<T>().Getter(entity);
                        record.SetValue(prop.Attribute.ColumnNumber, columnValue);
                    }
                }
                set.Insert(record);

                // Get Id of the inserted entity
                if (pkPropertyMetadata != null)
                {
                    object rawid = command.ExecuteScalar();
                    object convertedId = Convert.ChangeType(rawid, pkPropertyMetadata.Attribute.ColumnType, null);
                    pkPropertyMetadata.GetAccesssorDelegates<T>().Setter(entity, convertedId);
                }
                rowsEffected++;
            }
            return rowsEffected;
        }
    }
```

**Exception 1:**

```
Test 'M:Babil04_Mobil.Tests.ORMTests.Engine_Works' failed: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
at System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethods.ExecuteQueryPlan(IntPtr pTx, IntPtr pQpServices, IntPtr pQpCommand, IntPtr pQpPlan, IntPtr prgBinding, Int32 cDbBinding, IntPtr pData, Int32& recordsAffected, ResultSetOptions& cursorCapabilities, IntPtr& pSeCursor, Int32& fIsBaseTableCursor, IntPtr pError)
at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommandText(IntPtr& pCursor, Boolean& isBaseTableCursor)
at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteScalar()
MORMEngine.cs(182,0): at MORM.MORMEngine.Add[T](List`1 entities)
Tests\ORMTests.cs(187,0): at Babil04_Mobil.Tests.ORMTests.Engine_Works()
```

**Exception 2:**

```
Test 'M:Babil04_Mobil.Tests.ORMTests.Can_Insert_Multiple' failed: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'SqlCeResultSet'.
    System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
    Object name: 'SqlCeResultSet'.
    at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeResultSet.CreateRecord()
    MORMEngine.cs(162,0): at MORM.MORMEngine.Add[T](List`1 entities)
    Tests\ORMTests.cs(187,0): at Babil04_Mobil.Tests.ORMTests.Can_Insert_Multiple()
```

The unit test that calls the method throwing exception:

```
[Test]
    public void Can_Insert_Multiple()
    {
        MORMEngine engine = new MORMEngine(connectionString);
        engine.OpenConnection();

        List<TestInventory> inventories = new List<TestInventory>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            inventories.Add(new TestInventory
            {
                Code = "test" + i
            });
        }

        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        int rows = engine.Add<TestInventory>(inventories);

        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Completed in {0} ms.", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Assert.That(rows == 10000);
    }
```

Expcetions say that SqlCeResultSet is already **disposed**. Neither I call `Dispose()` method on the object nor set it to `null`. Why does it get disposed? Why does it run fine in Debug mode but not in Release mode?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm still thinking about the answer... but, just to let you know... I think your rows are affected

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. Rename your "set" variable to something else, just to make sure it isn't somehow confused with the keyword get/set (definitely shouldn't matter). 2. Turn off optimizations in release mode and test it again in release without optimizations (project properties)

Comment: I'm not going to commit this as an answer, but I'd be concerned by the fact that you're re-using `command` to fetch the insert ID, whilst still using the result set from the initial query. It may be that when you re-use it, the first result set becomes eligible GC and is finalized. I would suggest creating a second `SqlCeCommand` solely for running the "SELECT @@IDENTITY" query, and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Iridium I think you might be right. Though I think it doesn't have anything to do with GC, the `set` certainly won't be eligible for GC, because there is a local variable referencing it.

Comment: Another thing to note is that there appear to be no references to `engine` in the test after the call to `Add<...>(...)`, as a result in Release mode it's likely eligible for GC immediately after the `command.Connection = connection;` line in `Add<>()` (which is the last implicit `this` reference I see). Does `MORMEngine` implement a finalizer? If so, does that finalizer dispose the connection?

Comment: @Iridium, I created another separate command for getting the Id back, no luck.. MORMEngine implements IDisposable and closes the connection in the disposer. I think that cannot be an issue because other methods like Get<T>, Update<T> all use the same structure. Object name set is used in other methods too without any issue but I will check that too. Thanks for comments.

Comment: @svick, I agree. Other methods use the same structure without an issue. I think something weird happens in the loop because another method Add<T> adds single entity without any exceptions, identical to the one above that throws exceptions. The only difference is the loop.

Comment: @Alan, thanks for your comment. I turned off optimizations with hope but still same exceptions..

Comment: Does putting `GC.KeepAlive(engine);` on the line before `watch.Stop();` in the test make any difference to the result?

Comment: @Iridium, Thanks for the tip. Yep, that seems to solve the problem. Another solution I just discovered was to put using(){...} statement around that engine. Please post an answer containing both approaches, so I can mark it as answer. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my earlier comments - it appears that there are no references to `engine` in the test after the `int rows = engine.Add<TestInventory>(inventories);` line, and the only reference to `engine` (via an implicit `this`) in `Add<T>(List<T>)` is the line where the connection is accessed. Subsequent to this line, there are no further references to the engine, and so in Release mode it will become eligible for GC. It appears (given that my suggestion corrected the issue) that there may be a finalizer somewhere (either in your `MORMEngine`, or perhaps elsewhere) that is causing the connection to be disposed whilst `Add<>()` is still running. (In Debug mode, the lifetimes of objects is extended until they exit scope so as to simplify debugging, which is likely why this issue only appears in Release mode)

To ensure that the engine remains alive throughout the call to `Add<>()`, the following approaches appear to work:

```
...
        watch.Start();

        int rows = engine.Add<TestInventory>(inventories);

        GC.KeepAlive(engine); // Ensure that the engine remains alive until Add completes

        watch.Stop();
...
```

Or preferably explicitly dispose the `engine` with a `using()` statement:

```
[Test]
public void Can_Insert_Multiple()
{
    using (MORMEngine engine = new MORMEngine(connectionString))
    {
        engine.OpenConnection();

        List<TestInventory> inventories = new List<TestInventory>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            inventories.Add(new TestInventory
            {
                Code = "test" + i
            });
        }

        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        int rows = engine.Add<TestInventory>(inventories);

        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Completed in {0} ms.", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Assert.That(rows == 10000);
    }
}
```